# Compatibility of PlotLegend with Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The copy of Mathematica 8 I am using does not recognize the `PlotLegend` option for `Plot` and `ListPlot`. Specifically, it appears red when used.

A quick online search turns out nothing buggy/unusual, so I'm wondering what the problem is.

Comment: This is a great example of the kind of question that motivates the [proposed Mathematica site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica) IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't load the necessary package by any chance? That is, did you use:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
```